# why is numba dict lookup so much slower than cpython?

Tags: python, numba

I ran the following simple experiment:

```
import numba
import numpy as np
@njit
    def foo():
        d = dict()
        d[(1.0, 2)] = np.random.rand(500)
        return d
e = dict()
e[(1.0, 2)] = np.random.rand(500)
d = foo()
```

e and d are both dictionaries with one key each.

```
In [42]: %timeit e[(1.0, 2)][3]
123 ns ± 2.86 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
In [43]: %timeit d[(1.0, 2)][3]
1.99 µs ± 50.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Why is the numba dict 16 times slower?

This is with numba version 0.56.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably not the dictionary lookup that's slow, but the switching context from Python->Numba->Python that adds a significant overhead (for such a simple function).

Python dictionaries are also very fast, and well optimized. So as long as you stay within Python, that's hard to beat to begin with.

It's going to really depend on the actual use case whether something like that matters. Here's an alternative test, doing 1000 lookups in a function:

```py
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def create_numba_dict():
    return {(i,i): i for i in range(1000)} 

@njit
def index_numba_dict(d):
    
    total = 0.0
    for i in range(1000):
        total += d[(i,i)]

    return total
```

If I benchmark this with a warmup (to eliminate compilation overhead), these are the results I get:

```py
nb_dict = create_numba_dict()
index_numba_dict(nb_dict)
%timeit index_numba_dict(nb_dict)

py_dict = {(i,i): i for i in range(1000)}
%timeit sum([py_dict[(i,i)] for i in range(1000)])
```

[image]

There's of course a little more going on then only the lookup, in my experience you have to do something with the result, otherwise the compiler is sometimes clever enough to never even execute it. And it still isn't a very realistic scenario.

But I think it does show, that in the context of Numba, it's not the lookup that's intrinsically slow. Otherwise that should keep slowing down the total duration, regardless of the amount of lookups performed.

Comment: While using Numba dict in Numba functions is the way to go for sake of performance, the performance of accessing a dict outside a compiled function is abnormally high. A compiled function doing the wrapping/unwrapping is generally at least 4-5 time faster than the reported time. I guess the current implementation is not very efficient. This is sometimes an issue since Numba dicts sometimes needs to be filled from a code that cannot be compiled with Numba (eg. Scipy, Simpy, Pandas, etc.) and regular dict are not an option because the target dict is often meant to be provided to a Numba function

Comment: @JérômeRichard could you open an issue on this on the numba github?